# JMeter: Update Empty JSON hashmap groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter, beanshell, post-processor

Response from http request:

```
{"Preferredvalue":{"notations":[]}}
```

def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

I am able to get up to notations and also the size.

If the size is 0, I want to update the notations as below

```
{"Preferredvalue":{"notations":[{"Name":${firstName},"lName":${lastName}}]}
```

firstName and lastName are Jmeter variable which are fetched from another calls, and I want to use these values in my another call and send a PUT request.

Searched a lot but couldnt find an answer :(

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

def notations = response.Preferredvalue.notations

if (notations.size() == 0) {
    notations.add([Name: vars.get('firstName'), lName: vars.get('lastName')])
}

def request = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(response).toPrettyString()

vars.put('request', request)
```

should do the trick for you. Refer generated value as `${request}` where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)